# Can django filter queryset based on a dictionary field?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework

I am diving to a django rest-api framework that someone else wrote and configured, and I came across a problem I could not find any good solution for.

There is a model containing field of type "YAMLField". While trying to retrieve this field member, it is converted to OrderedDict (not quite sure how and where this conversion is happening...).

Now, I have a queryset of this model. I understand how to filter a queryset based on simple attributes, but how can I filter it based on this dictionary?

For example, each entry in this queryset (which is MyModel instance) contains:

```
MyModel.myDictionary == {'firstKey': 'firstVal', 'secondKey':'secondVal}
```

Now I want to get all the entries from this queryset where:

```
myDictionary = {'firstKey': 'Something'}
```

Meaning, my dictionary to filter by, may contain only a subset of the keys.

I could not find any solution or a straight forward way to do it, leading me to iterate the queryset and for each entry, iterate the dictionary.
This feels like too much overhead...

Comment: If I understood all correctly and your dictionary keys are primary keys of model, then you can use my_dictionary.keys() to get all keys as list and use it in queryset field lookup like MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=my_dictionary.keys()). Don't forget to name variables and field in PEP8 style with underscores, not CamelCase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dictionary keys are not primary model keys. The dictionary is a model key, but I want to filter based on the content of the dictionary.

I ended up with using the fact this is a YAMLField, and made a regex search in that field, after I concated all of the values I want to filter from that dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had the same problem and someone told me an straightforward answer, which consists in adding "__{dictionary_key}" to your filtering request such as, in your case:

```
 Model.objects.all().filter(myDictionary__firstKey="Something")
```

Though the asnwer is probably coming too late, I post it hoping that it can be useful for others in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You need this is possible. For more information see django-rest-framework [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins)

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure it's going to work for what I need, or maybe I just didn't fully understand it. Anyway, I found another solution, as I wrote in the comment of my question.
Thanks again for your help